# Whats is that label "Formatted" on the right side of Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got a word document from some colleague. After I have done some changes in formatting of that document: inserted section breaks, changed numeration etc And exactly after this a strange gray area emerged on the right side of each page and inside that area there are comments which look like "Formatted" etc in red boxes with arrows.

Please tell me what is this and how can I turn it off or fix?

Answer (score 2):

#### A strange gray area emerged on the right side of each page

> Inside that area there are comments which look like "Formatted" etc in red boxes with arrows.

These are tracked changes and comments.

Set "Display for Review" to "Final" to display the document with all changes incorporated into the text and without tracked changes showing.

See below for instructions.

---

#### Show or hide Track Changes revision marks

> To prevent you from inadvertently distributing documents that contain
> tracked changes and comments, Word displays tracked changes and
> comments by default. Final Showing Markup is the default option in the
> Display for Review box.
>
> You can display all changes in a document in different ways. For
> example, you can set Microsoft Office Word to display tracked changes
> by type of edit — such as insertions and deletions or formatting
> changes. You can also display only the comments. You can turn off
> balloons for comments and tracked changes to display all comments and
> changes inline. You can even display only the changes made by the
> author or by a specific reviewer.
>
> To quickly display tracked changes and comments, click Show Markup in
> the Tracking group on the Review tab.
>
> Note   Clicking Show Markup displays or hides all of the markup for
> selected reviewers in the document. When you display all markup, all
> types of markup are selected on the Show Markup menu.

...

> You can use the Display for Review list, in the Tracking group, to
> view a document at various stages of the edit process. Each of the
> four options in the list provides a different view of the document.
> Final Showing Markup is the default when you open any document.
>
> [image]
>
> - Final Showing Markup -   This view displays the final document with all tracked changes and comments showing. This is the default view for
>   all documents opened in Word.
> - **Final -   This view displays the document with all changes incorporated into the text and without tracked changes showing.**
>   However, any tracked changes or comments that have not been accepted,
>   rejected, or deleted remain in the document.
> - Original Showing Markup -   This view displays the original text with tracked changes and comments.
> - Original -   This view displays the original document without tracked changes and comments showing. However, any tracked changes or
>   comments in the document that have not been accepted, rejected, or
>   deleted remain in the document.

Note in Word 2016, the names of these options have changed:

- "Simple Markup" (Somewhat new),
- "All Markup" (instead of "Final Showing Markup"),
- "No Markup" (instead of "Final") and
- "Original"

Source [Show or hide Track Changes revision marks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/show-or-hide-track-changes-revision-marks-HP001219412.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Go to review tab, in tracking box click the drop down box and select the option "FINAL" . Your problem will be solved.